# How to change the master page

Tags: master-page

How can I change the master page of only one of the many sites in my 2007 sharepoint site. I do not have production site access so i cannot use designer.

Pavan.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your master page for a specific site by going to the following url `http://{your-site-collection-url/{your-subsite}/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` or by going through site action > site settings > Master Page.

From there you can specify another master page for that site. Be careful NOT to check the checkbox "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting" as you only want this change for a specific (sub)site.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure to change the *correct* master page. Which master page you need to change depends on what type of site you are using. See a [related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43604/set-as-default-master-page-vs-set-as-custom-master-page).